# Prove that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f^2(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ = $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f^4(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ = $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f^3(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

And $f$ is continious on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Honestly , i tried everything i could , i can't see how the integrals would help since they are definite.

i accomplished one thing , $f$ passes on the interval $[-1,1]$.

i start by  supposing that there exists n such that : $f'(n)>0$

but honestly , with these integrals i can't see how we can achieve a contradiction

Comment: Can you say with any degree of confidence _what_ the constant value that $f(x)$ has on $[a,b]$ might be?

Comment: I just want to verify notation. By $f^2(x)$, do you mean $f''(x)$ or $(f(x))^2$?

Comment: Well, an alternative to Jimmy's approach would be to note that $\int_a^b f^2(x)dx + \int_a^b f^4(x)dx - 2\int_a^bf^3(x)dx = 0$, and go on directly from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the [Cauchy Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), for any integrable function $f(x)$:

$\displaystyle\left(\int_a^b f(x) \cdot f(x)^2\,dx\right)^2 \le \left(\int_a^b f(x)^2\,dx\right) \left(\int_a^b (f(x)^2)^2\,dx\right)$

$\displaystyle\left(\int_a^b f(x)^3\,dx\right)^2 \le \left(\int_a^b f(x)^2\,dx\right) \left(\int_a^b f(x)^4\,dx\right)$

But by the given conditions, we have equality, which holds iff $f(x)^2$ is a constant multiple of $f(x)$, i.e. $f(x)^2 = cf(x)$, i.e. $f(x) = c$.

Comment: Since $f(x)*f(x)^2=f(x)^3$, aren't the two inequalities you have here saying the same thing?

Comment: Since $f(x)^2=cf(x)$, either $f(x)=c$ or $f(x)=0$. Continuity is necessary since $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}1&\text{for }x\in[0,1]\\0&\text{for }x\in(1,2]\end{array}\right.$$ also satisfies the equations, but is not constant.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is $f$ constant, that constant is either $0$ or $1$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b\left[f(x)^2-f(x)\right]^2\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^b\left[f(x)^4-2f(x)^3+f(x)^2\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(f(x)-1)f(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in[a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have either $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[a,b]$ or $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: how? if the integral from a to b of f is 0 then f=0?

Comment: If the integral of the *square* of $f$ is $0$, then $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere. Continuity handles the rest.